# How many unique sets do you get if you pair 8 girls and 8 boys?

Tags: combinatorics

If I have 2 girls and 2 boys, let's call them Anne, Brooke, Andrew and Benjamin, we have 2 unique sets:

Set 1:
Anne - Andrew
Brooke - Benjamin

Set 2:
Anne - Benjamin
Brooke - Andrew

Likewise, for 3 girls and 3 boys I believe there are 6 unique sets. Unfortunately I am unable to calculate this other than simply listing up the various sets, which quickly becomes impossible to keep track of. Therefore I'm wondering how to calculate this in terms of math and how many unique sets you'd have for 8 girls and 8 boys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you line the girls up in alphabetical order, then it's the same as asking "With $8$ boys and $8$ places to put them, how many ways can you put them down?"

This is the archetypical example of a question where the answer is $8! = 1\cdot 2 \cdot 3\cdots 8 = 40320$.

The reasoning is this: Say you choose seats for the boys in alphabetical order (it doesn't matter for the end arrangement, and it's easier to keep track of if we decide on an order first). So first up is Andrew. Andrew has $8$ places he can be seated, so there are $8$ possibilities so far. Then along comes Benjamin. For each possibility of where to put Andrew, there are $7$ new possibilities for where to put Benjamin, so for those two togwether it's $8\cdot 7 = 56$ possibilities.

Next one is Charlie, who makes it $8\cdot 7\cdot 6 = 336$. Then Daniel, Edward, Fred and George all get their places, and there are in total $8\cdot 7 \cdots 2 = 40320$ ways to distribute the seven boys so far. Poor Harold only has one spot left for him when it's his turn, so he has no choice, and we end up with $40320$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) of the number of boys/girls, $n!=\prod_{k=1}^nk=1\cdot2\cdot...\cdot (n-1)\cdot n$.

Consider: you can line up all the girls in the same order every time, the way you have in your example for $n=2$; then you can merely arrange the boys.  Now, how can you arrange the boys?  The simple way is to build a line of boys and then attach them to the line of girls.  So let's do that, by having the boys enter the room in order.

- **Andrew** comes in and there's no line yet so we just put him in; there's only one way this can go.
- **Benjamin** comes in an there's Andrew, and he can stand in front of Andrew or behind him.  Two places.
- **Charlie** comes in and Andrew and Benjamin are all lined up.  He can stand at the front of the line, or the back of the line, or between the two people.  Three places.
- **David** comes in an there's three people in line, so he can cut in to become the first, second, third, or fourth person in line.  Four places.
- **Edward** comes in, four people in line, five places to stand.
- And so on.

So each new boy that comes in has more places to stand, and they don't affect the previous arrangement.  So we can just multiply each boy's choice space by the previous number of possible arrangements... which leads to the formula above.